# A question on Boyd's book about Simplexes

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, simplex

In [page 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjog3.png) and [page 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUBoC.png) of Boyd's [convex optimization book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), he said there exists a nonsingular matrix $A = (A_1, A_2) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, such that

$AB = \begin{bmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2\end{bmatrix}B = \begin{bmatrix}I \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

I'm not sure how $A$ can be nonsingular because as $B$ contains linearly independent vectors, to get a zero on the RHS, then an entire row of $A$ will b 0. And also, why such $A$ exist that $A_1 B = I$? $B$ is not even a square matrix.

Comment: Are you sure it isn’t $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}?$ Or what is the dimension of $B?$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, with $k \leq n$, and $B$ is assumed to be full rank.

This means that the columns of $B$ are linearly independent. Therefore, we can choose $A_1 = B^{\dagger} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ (the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $B$). When $B$ has linearly independent columns we have

$$
B^{\dagger} B = \underbrace{(B^* B)^{-1} B^*}_{B^{\dagger}} B = I_{k}.
$$

For $A_2$, we can choose any matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{(n - k) \times n}$ whose rows span the orthogonal complement of the column span of $B$.